# Web Service call returning SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I'm  calling a web service that returns data of the cheapest price of the object you searched for. For now, I'm hardcoding the URL to just search for "Logitech" brand items. For some reason, whenever I attempt to use a single response key phrase like "title" or "id", I'm ALWAYS getting a SIGABRT error like this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8dbc2e0'
```

My web service call is in my viewDidLoad method, and looks like this:

```
  NSString *urlString =@"http://us.api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/products?query=Logitech&app_id=dad00cb7&app_key=ab386c3e1b99b58b876f237d77b4211a";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSMutableArray *itemCallArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];


for (NSDictionary *theItem in itemCallArray)
{
    NSString *titleString = theItem[@"brands"];
    NSLog(@"%@", titleString);


}
```

I'm pulling my hair out on this one. All help would be appreciated, and thank you in advance :)

EDIT:

When I log the itemCallArray, I get this (a lot of stuff):

```
 errors =     (
);
info =     {
    start = 0;
    "total_results" = 4775;
};
results =     (
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/20352/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F20352%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/20352/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech Classic Keyboard  920003199";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = cc2565b3d498073b74d6fc2baa9155d3;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/cc2565b3d498073b74d6fc2baa9155d3";
        title = "Logitech Classic Keyboard  920003199";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/17951/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F17951%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/17951/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech K120 USB Keyboard  920002478";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = d46e49d5b7a0f85f5b7e4eaaeded480e;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/d46e49d5b7a0f85f5b7e4eaaeded480e";
        title = "Logitech K120 USB Keyboard  920002478";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/18226/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F18226%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/18226/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech Z506 5.1 Speakers  980000430";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = 7f1b492e40e2a8956475f24f74c0e152;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/7f1b492e40e2a8956475f24f74c0e152";
        title = "Logitech Z506 5.1 Speakers  980000430";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/23904/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F23904%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/23904/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech M235 Wireless Mouse Light Silver  910002332";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = 58fc508d545168dccf81f93bb6070ac3;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/58fc508d545168dccf81f93bb6070ac3";
        title = "Logitech M235 Wireless Mouse Light Silver  910002332";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/23916/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F23916%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/23916/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech Wireless Combo Mk520 With Keyboard and Laser Mouse   920002553";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = ae530f45af7ac34207bd9a44406afa98;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/ae530f45af7ac34207bd9a44406afa98";
        title = "Logitech Wireless Combo Mk520 With Keyboard and Laser Mouse   920002553";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/16215/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F16215%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/16215/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech LS21 2.1 Stereo Speaker System  980000058";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = ad59cd583a1b88c782f8af77e6d71494;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/ad59cd583a1b88c782f8af77e6d71494";
        title = "Logitech LS21 2.1 Stereo Speaker System  980000058";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/16216/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F16216%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/16216/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech Compact 25Watt 2.1 Speaker System  980000382";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = 54c5479754c659a2fac08018a4bce795;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/54c5479754c659a2fac08018a4bce795";
        title = "Logitech Compact 25Watt 2.1 Speaker System  980000382";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/22841/Logitech";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicexpress.com%2Fcatalog%2F22841%2FLogitech";
            "original_url" = "http://www.electronicexpress.com/catalog/22841/Logitech";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Electronicexpress.com";
            title = "Logitech Z130 Compact Laptop Speakers   980000417";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = 7218f2482c0b4f40cf89d57feabb8c58;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/7218f2482c0b4f40cf89d57feabb8c58";
        title = "Logitech Z130 Compact Laptop Speakers   980000417";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        "best_page" =             {
            currency = USD;
            deeplink = "http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104828";
            description = "<null>";
            "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
            "in_stock" = 1;
            "live_price_url" = "http://api.invisiblehand.co.uk/v1/pages/live_price?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newegg.com%2FProduct%2FProduct.aspx%3FItem%3DN82E16826104828";
            "original_url" = "http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104828";
            pnp = 0;
            price = "<null>";
            "price_confidence" = low;
            region = us;
            "retailer_name" = "Newegg.com";
            title = "Logitech Corded Mouse M318e";
        };
        brands =             (
            Logitech
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = b5ccd2875b684f2209b2972ad85ab529;
        "image_url" = "http://shopping.getinvisiblehand.com/images/no_image_available.png";
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 1;
        resource = "/products/b5ccd2875b684f2209b2972ad85ab529";
        title = "Logitech Corded Mouse M318e";
        upcs =             (
        );
    },
            {
        asins =             (
        );
        brands =             (
        );
        categories =             (
        );
        eans =             (
        );
        id = 65e25398341ecdca6c54787cf1f3e5d6;
        isbns =             (
        );
        models =             (
        );
        mpns =             (
        );
        "number_of_pages" = 0;
        resource = "/products/65e25398341ecdca6c54787cf1f3e5d6";
        title = "<null>";
        upcs =             (
        );
    }
);
```

}

Comment: Can you show the result of logging `itemCallArray`?

Comment: ok, i get A LOT of stuff, ill add it to the question

Comment: Should I try to call the results array in the for loop? And then attempt to get an object from THAT array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data source isn't exactly what you think it is. The root object appears to be a dictionary, containing your results array as one of its keys. I would try this instead.

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *itemCallArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:dataDictionary[@"results"]];
```